# Неправильное отображение ссылки ввода\регистрации

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, span

В файл `C:\OSPanel\OpenServer\domains\shop.ru\wp-content\themes\twentytwenty\header.php` добавил строчки с 85-ой по 100-ю

```html
<div class="header-navigation-authblock">
    <a href="#">
        <span>
            <span>
                <div class="header-navigation-authblockimage">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/greenicon.jpg" width="70px" height="70px" class="entrylink3"></img>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span>
                <div class="header-navigation-authblocklabel">
                    Войти
                </div>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

а в файл `C:OSPanel\OpenServer\domains\shop.ru\wp-content\themes\twentytwenty\style.css` cтроки с 6491-ой по 6514-ю

```html
.header-navigation-authblock {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

//**.header-navigation-authblock,*// .header-navigation-authblockimage, .header-navigation-authblocklabel {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-navigation-authblock:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header-navigation-authblockimage, .header-navigation-authblocklabel {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Но в результате получаю скриншот

[image: Двухстрочный вход\регистрация]

но должно быть расположено в одну строку из-за тегов `span` и `display: flex`. Как добиться желаемого отображения?

Comment: нельзя так работать с темой. Ваши изменения потеряются при первом же обновление темы. Нужно работать через child тему https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ и в ней уже делать корректировки

Answer (score 0):

Располагать div внутри span не стоит. Если вы хотите добиться нужного результата уберите все теги span, а flex примените к тегу a, непосредственно внутри которого и будут эти 2 divа.